# Gradle project sync failed. Unresolved dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I downloaded my repository through `git` on a new computer, cloned everything, but when I ran a `Gradle` sync it failed with this error message:

[image: error message]

I tried cleaning the project, invalidating caches / restart, redownload the whole repository, delete `Gradle` file and get it back from the repository. Nothing helped. Funny thing is, the guys at the office are building without a problem from the same `Gradle` file. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Btw, I checked all the 20+ threads here on SO with similar titles, but none of them described the same problem I'm having. However, I tried all the fixes suggested there, but that didn't show any results either.

Comment: Did you check that you have all the necessary repositories in your (project)   build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes I have. All repositories are there.

Comment: Please check if you still have your project files at E:/Documents/Android Projects/

Comment: I do. All of them are there. Freshly downloaded from the repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After wasting a whole day on this I found out the core of the problem.It was a problem with `Gradle`. The links for these four dependencies pointed to pages, which returned 404, therefor `Android Studio` couldn't get the dependencies and threw this error. My temporary decision is to use a different `Gradle` version, in which the links point to the right pages.

Comment: What Gradle version did cause the problem and which version solved it?

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps I was using Gradle 4.1 and switched to 4.2, though I tried switching to any version after 4.1 and they all worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add google() in your app build.gradle.
1. buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        .....
    }
   }
2. allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        .....
   }
  }

Then try to build.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already had google() in my gradle file. The problem was with the links for the repositories, as described in the approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK manager and choose the target SDK version then click ok , it will start installing the version directly.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfNSe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Open File > Project Structure in window select versions as my.

[image]

After that sync gradle

resolve for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).